# I got a blank screen after coding this section in my react app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

After coding this I got a blank screen as an output. after removing that usestate function, the error is fixed, but I need to set up a sanity backend to react website. to do that I need to use that  useState and use effect hooks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

import "./About.scss";
import { urlFor, client } from "../../client";

const About = () => {
  
  const [abouts, setAbouts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "abouts"]';

    client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
      setAbouts(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h2 className='head-text'>
        I Know that <span>Good Design</span> <br />
        means <span>Good Business</span>
      </h2>

      <div className='app__profiles'>
        {abouts.map((about, index) => (
          <motion.div
            whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.5, type: "tween" }}
            className='app__profile-item'
            key={about.title + index}
          >
            <img src={urlFor(about.imgUrl)} alt={about.title} />
            <h2 className='bold-text' style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
              {about.title}
            </h2>
            <p className='p-text' style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
              {about.description}
            </p>
          </motion.div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default About;
```

Comment: check your browser console, there should be an error. check and update the question with that.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

check the about.title and about.imgurl if they are same as the one on sanity backend